# different methods indexing numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, data-structures

If I have an NxN NumPy array, and I wanted to get all rows of data from just the 5th column, is there any difference between the following methods:

```
just_the_fifth_a = somearray[0::,4]

just_the_fifth_b = somearray[0:,4]

just_the_fifth_c = somearray[:,4]
```

Comment: somearray[:-1,4] too.  What are you looking for in terms of differences?

Comment: `somearray[:-1,4]` lops a value off the end.  But the `stop` value may be the shape or larger, or may be `None`.

Comment: I was just looking through a tutorial and noticed that it used all of the styles I mentioned and was wondering if there was a reason for the inconsistency other than exposing reader to different styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no difference between the three posted methods. You could do `somearray[::,4]` as well.